# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'yii\widgets\ActiveForm' not found C:\wamp64\www\yii-basic\views\post\index.php

Tags: php, yii2, fatal-error

I faced this error at the following code and I can't solve it. What should I do? I'm a beginner in Yii2.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'yii\widgets\ActiveForm' not found C:\wamp64\www\yii-basic\views\post\index.php

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Html;
?>
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
'id'=>'post-form',
'options'=>['class'=>'form-horizontal']
]);
?>
<?= $form->field('$model','title');?>
<?= $form->field('$model','content')->textarea();?>
<?= $form->field('$model','tags');?>
<?= $form->field('$model','status')->checkbox();?>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
    <?= Html::submitButton('save',['class','btn btn-success']) ?>
</div>
</div>

<?php
ActiveForm::end();
?>
```

Comment: `yii\widgets\ActiveForm` should be in `vendor/yiisoft/yii2/widgets/ActiveForm.php`. if you don't have this file, then it means that your installation is incomplete. Try delete `vendor` directory and run `composer install` again.

Answer (score 1):

#### You are missing them in your directory.

Your error is on this line:

```
 use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
```

The problem is that there is no file in that directory named ActiveForm.

Since it was a fatal error it stopped processing the code after that line. You will have to check if you have 'yii\helpers\Html' too.

**Solution**

Check your folders to see if those files are in there. If not then re verify the installation was successful with Yii.

```
php yii serve
```

Sources: [Yii-Installation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation) [PHP-Namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: I found this file in yii-basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/src/ActiveForm directory, but I don't know why this error occurs?

Comment: Does it work if you change your use to: use yii-basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/src/ActiveForm; ?

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that you found `ActiveForm` in `yii-basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/src/ActiveForm` Directory, I think you should

**Replace**

```
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
```

**With**

```
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
```

because, you have installed yii2 bootstrap active form.